# Daisy Chain and switch not working

Tags: lighting, circuit

I am replacing the light switches in my house and came across this weird configuration. The switch on the bottom goes to a ceiling fan/light that also has another switch on the circuit. The switch on the top goes to a hallway light that has two other switches on its circuit. I do not know why the two switches are daisy chained together. After replacing all the switches, I somehow messed up the wiring and now the ceiling fan/light combo does not work. The hallway switch works fine. Not sure what to do or if the two even need to be daisy chained, since they are not truly controlling lights in the same space.

[image]

[image: light switches for viewing]

Comment: Restore it to the way it was before you did any work and then take some pictures, labling the wires. The picture you included does not tell us much

Answer (score 3):

You've daisy chained a 3-way traveller screw.  It seems that you've seriously misunderstood how to connect the switches.

Based on the description, this circuit has a 3-way fan and a 4-way hall light.  In that case, a 3-way replacement switch is appropriate, but you've connected it wrong.

You've also made some errors by connecting white wires to these switches without identifying them as required by code, and failing to ground the switches as required by code.

Unless you have original photos from before the bad work, you'll need someone to take apart all the other switches on the 3-way and 4-way loads and sort out where every one of those wires belongs.